# How to set model attributes on collection.create with POST request in php code?

Tags: javascript, php, backbone.js, symfony

i don't know how to handle the request in my controller in symfony in the php code. So im creating a new model in my collection with collection.create() method but I don't know how to handle it in symfony php code. Can anyone help me?

Collection.create() code:

```
save: function()
    {            
            this.collection.create({
                    title: $("#title").val()
            });
            console.log(this.collection);
    }
```

PHP code:

```
/**
     * @Route("/document")
    */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
    $content = $request->getContent();

    $document = new Document();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $em->persist($document);

    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse($document);
}
```

Request method: POST, status: OK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be you forget to set the properties on the Document object

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
  $document = new Document();
```

> ```
> $document->setTitle($request->get('title'));
> ```

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $em->persist($document);

  $em->flush();

  return new JsonResponse($document);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what are your Document Entity properties, it is only an example

Comment: In Document entity i have id, title, document, and user_id. And the set and the get methods.

Comment: Ok,can you show the post parameters of the request in the browser debug?

Comment: You mean the Request Payload?

Comment: Yes... excuse my bad english

Comment: Request Payload:
{title: "test"}

    title: "test"

Here i got this

Comment: I edited my response for the payload, BTW you can access the symfony profiler of the ajax request in the response headers X-debug-token and X-Debug-Token-Link and see the DB querys, etc

Comment: It won't save it into database :( I have two routes with same names /document, how can i specify to execute the route for saving attributes into databas, i need to specify that method in the route or?

Comment: And im getting this error on symfony page in Preview when im trying to save: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "" at line 0!

Comment: This last error is probably caused by a .php file that have something before the <?php tag (one or more spaces, break-lines)

Comment: It's nothing before the <?php tag, the tag is on the first line of the code. I don't get it, how won't it save the model to database.